# input[type="submit"] - change background when clicked

Tags: html, css, input, submit

I have a simple `<input type="submit" value="Search">` submit button.
In the CSS i have styled it with `input[type="submit"]` and `input[type="submit"]:hover` so it changes its background by default and when hovered. Is there a way to change its background when clicked?

Comment: onclick javascript ability can be used to set element styles

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use `input[type=submit]:active`, similar to how you'd style links.

Do note that this will not function properly in IE6 (not sure about 7 and 8)

Comment: Oh, I don't mind IE6-IE7 compatibilty...
Thank you all, it was so simple that I forgot it :D

Answer (score 5):

```
input[type="submit"]:active {
    color: green;
}
```